# dsym file UUID doesn't match the one in xx, No symbol table is loaded in eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, eclipse-cdt, symlink

I am trying to debug a C++ project in eclipse CDT. It builds fine and runs fine. 
I don't know what is wrong. I wonder if there's any link that I set wrong. I am getting this error: warning: dsym file UUID doesn't match the one in /Users/project-path/src/simple_client
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.`

I have latest gdb/ggdb installed by macports. 
Also, should I choose Cross GCC or MAcOSX toolchain please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in some cases, it helps to "make clean" and than "rm -fr simple_client.dSYM" in the binary build folder. 
Also you may want to read this http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2007/Dec/msg00139.html

Comment: Thanks so much. it should work. But I re-installed my machine already.... Still great thanks.